# True or false: $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(\int _2^{\:e^x}\:\ln t \,dt)=x-\ln 2$. Support with a proof

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, solution-verification

> True or false: $\frac{d}{dx}(\int _2^{\:e^x}\:\ln t \,dt)=x-\ln 2$. Support with a proof

---

I think it is false. I used the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$\int _2^{\:e^x}\:\ln t\,dt\:=\:\int _0^{e^x}\ln t\:-\:\int _0^2\ln t\,dt$$

The second integral $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int _0^2\ln t\right)dt=\ln 2$

The first integral $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int _0^{e^x}\ln t\:\right)=\frac{d\left(e^x\right)}{dx}\frac{d}{d\left(e^x\right)}\int _0^{e^x}\ln t\:=e^xx$

Combining the terms $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int _2^{\:e^x}\:\ln t\,dt\:\right)=e^xx-\ln 2,$$ 
I saw the solution of the same question on a [website](https://www.abstractclasses.in/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/MTE-01-Assignment-Solution-2020-1-01.jpg), and its answer is different from mine. Is my solution wrong?

Comment: The second integral does not depend on $x$ so it's derivative is $0$ not $\ln 2$.

Comment: Compare $lnt$ to `$\ln t$`: $\ln t$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first step replaces a perfectly normal definite integral with two diverging [improper integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral), so you are already on shaky ground.  The logarithm is undefined at zero, so it is not immediate that the integrals on $[0,2]$ and $[0,\mathrm{e}^x]$ are defined.  Far better is to split the interval of integration at a point where the integrand is well-behaved, for instance at $1$.

$$  \int_2^{\mathrm{e}^x} \ln(t) \,\mathrm{d}t =  \int_1^{\mathrm{e}^x} \ln(t) \,\mathrm{d}t - \int_1^{2} \ln(t) \,\mathrm{d}t  $$
This result should make it clear that it doesn't matter whether we split the interval of integration, we are faced with a minor variation of the same integral minus zero.  So don't split.

Next, the definite integral $\int_1^{2} \ln(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$ is just some number, so $$  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_1^{2} \ln(t) \,\mathrm{d}t = 0  \text{.}  $$

Finally, let $u(x) = \mathrm{e}^x$ and $f(u) = \int_1^{u} \ln(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$.  Then, \begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_1^{\mathrm{e}^x} \ln(t) \,\mathrm{d}t
    &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} f(u(x))  \\
    &= \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}u} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}  \\
    &= \ln(u) \cdot \mathrm{e}^x  \\
    &= x \cdot \mathrm{e}^x  \text{.}  
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! Can you suggest a good book for learning integration. I'm a struggling undergrad student

Comment: Why split into two integrals at all? The OP did that, and I think it's part of the OP's misunderstanding of the question. But in your solution, how is $\int_1^{e^x}\ln t\,\mathrm{d}t$ any better than $\int_2^{e^x}\ln t\,\mathrm{d}t$? Even without referencing the FTC, there's no need to split the original integral into two. I think, from a pedgogical perspective it's worth demonstrating to the OP that it was not necessary. Nevertheless, (+1) for a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you write
$$ F(y) = \int_2^y  \log t dt $$
then as you note ("FTOC") $$ F'(y) = \log y $$
and
$$\begin{align} \frac{d}{dx} F\left(e^x\right) &= F'\left( e^x \right) \frac{d}{dx} e^x \\ &=\log\left( e^x \right) e^x  \\ &= xe^x\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{d}{{dx}}\int_2^{e^x } {\log tdt} \mathop  = \limits^{t = e^s } \frac{d}{{dx}}\int_{\log 2}^x {se^s ds}  = xe^x.
$$